# Highlight SwiftUI Button programmatically

Tags: swiftui

I've been trying to highlight programmatically a SwiftUI `Button`, without success so far…

Of course I could implement the whole thing again, but I'd really like to take advantage of what SwiftUI already offers. I would imagine that there is an environment or state variable that we can mutate, but I couldn't find any of those.

Here's a small example of what I would like to achieve:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var highlighted = false

    var body: some View {
        Button("My Button", action: doSomething())
            .highlighted($highlighted) // <-- ??

        Button("Toggle highlight") {
            highlighted.toggle()
        }
    }

   func doSomething() { ... }
}
```

It seems very odd that something so simple if not within easy reach in SwiftUI. Has anyone found a solution?

Comment: Could you provide your code with where/how (on which condition) do you want to *highlight* button? And what do you mean by *highlight* - color, border, text... and when/how it to be unhighlight? Because a goal is a bit ambiguous.

Comment: Sure, let me edit the question. Regarding what I mean by _highlight_, it's really everything that SwiftUI does: background color, color… depending on the context.

Comment: If you mean make button perform default highlight, then it is not possible for now in SwiftUI. If you mean custom highlight, then you need ButtonStyle, look for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62678306/how-do-i-change-button-backgroundcolor-if-the-button-is-disabled-in-swiftui, the approach to solution would be the same.

Comment: Thanks @Asperi, I still can’t believe that there’s no way to access the configuration’s `isPressed` property, even in iOS 14. This is such a basic behavior that I would expect from any UI framework!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a demo of possible approach, based on custom `ButtonStyle`. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

[image: demo]

```
struct HighlightButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    let highlighted: Bool

    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .background(highlighted || configuration.isPressed ? Color.yellow : Color.clear)
    }
}

extension Button {
    func highlighted(_ flag: Bool) -> some View {
        self.buttonStyle(HighlightButtonStyle(highlighted: flag))
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var highlighted = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("My Button", action: doSomething)
                .highlighted(highlighted)
            Divider()
            Button("Toggle highlight") {
                self.highlighted.toggle()
            }
        }
    }

   func doSomething() { }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is more of a workaround, as we override the default behavior provided by SwiftUI though. I’ll try to look into that a bit more.

Comment: Hello from 2022, thanks for the answer. I still can't believe Apple does not have this option in their Button!